# Converting to "discord.member" failed for parameter "member"

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx,user : discord.member):
    if user==None:
        user=ctx.author
    
    test=Image.open("test.jpg")

    asset=ctx.author.avatar_url_as(size=128)
    data = BytesIO(await asset.read())
    pfp=Image.open(data)
    pfp=pfp.resize((177,177))
    test.paste(pfp,(446,339))


    test.save("test1.jpg")
    await ctx.send(file=discord.file('test1.jpg'))
```

its not working and i am getting following errors

if i type !test it would show me this error
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: user is a required argument that is missing.

but if use !test @mention.some.username it will show me this error
Converting to "discord.member" failed for parameter "user".

Comment: `discord.member` is a module, you need the class [`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#discord.Member) with capital M.

Comment: yea its already capital M my bad i pasted small m here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two mistakes that you are doing here.

- `discord.member` is a module, You are meant to use `discord.Member` class for annotation of `user`.
- You are doing:

  ```py
  if user == None:
    user = ctx.author
  ```

  but you haven't set a default value to user so it is a required argument.

The correct way is:

```py
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, user: discord.Member = None):
  if user is None:
    user = ctx.author

  # rest of code here
```

We just declared a default value to the user as `None` and properly annotate `user` as `discord.Member`

Comment: done.. but then i get this error 

discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
and the photo is being saved and edited for my own profile picture but not for others.

Comment: It's discord.File. Not discord.file. Classes names are in title case.

Comment: oh yeah, it worked thanks for helping never thought it would be a basic mistake :P

Answer (score 0):

just remove `user : discord.member` and it should work fine

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):

    user=ctx.author
    
    test=Image.open("test.jpg")

    asset=ctx.author.avatar_url_as(size=128)
    data = BytesIO(await asset.read())
    pfp=Image.open(data)
    pfp=pfp.resize((177,177))
    test.paste(pfp,(446,339))


    test.save("test1.jpg")
    await ctx.channel.send(file=discord.file('test1.jpg'))
```

Comment: it shows me this error
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
and the photo is being saved and edited for my own profile picture but not for others.